# C# - Totally hide a folder

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently trying to make a C# program to hide folders, but if i try to use

```
string fold = this.folder;
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@fold);

//See if directory has hidden flag, if not, make hidden
if ((di.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
{
    //Add Hidden flag    
    di.Attributes |= FileAttributes.Hidden;
}
```

it can be seen if the "Show hidden folders" option is set on, and I want it to be completely invisible.

Thanks for the help, in advance!

Comment: There's no such thing as "completely invisible". Actually there is, it's called deleting the folder.

Comment: No you can't do it with standard APIs unless you find something in *hacking* sites (for ex binary editing the sectors of disk)

Comment: Sounds SHADY, why would you ever need to completely hide a folder?

Comment: You can't do this. Explain the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: What's your intent here? Users with enough rights will always be able to view the folders. This is by definition. (Relevant Old New Thing link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx)

Comment: @Chris - I can think of a number of reasons one might want to completely hide a folder... but as you said, they're all "shady".

Comment: Why does this question get down votes? It might be shady what the OP is asking for but the question in itself isn't of bad quality, or is it?

Comment: I just want to make a program like a "Lock Box" that you can see around the internet :P

Comment: `I just want to make a program like a "Lock Box" that you can see around the internet` this is a good reason to close the question as `too broad`

Comment: I just want a way to hide the folder enven if the explorer "Show hidden folders" option is on D:

Comment: @GGG We know it, and say you can't do it (with your current knowledge) BTW: SO is not a place to share hacking codes.... So you are on the wrong side.

Comment: Well, as I didn't found a way of doing it with C#, i think I'll just run the command prompt with the command `attrib +s +h “<folder>”`

Comment: @GGG you are helpless. No you can't do it. Reread my very first comment.

Comment: @L.B I read it, but i tried using the command on cmd and it worked... And i remember that there was a way of doing it with batch

Comment: Even more appropriate link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/19/409620.aspx Key point: "**As a matter of security, a sufficiently-privileged user must always have a way of seeing what is there or at least know that there is something there that can't be seen.**"

Comment: @GGG You don't know the technology you are using and it can't be done with legal windows APIs. This is why you didn't get any answer tiil now. If you are after on a *hacking solution*, then you are on the wrong side.

Comment: With that attrib command you have set your folder **Hidden** and **System**, but your user could see it again if it checks `Show hidden files and folders` and uncheck `Hide protected opperating system files`. Back to start.

Comment: SOrry, i think that I didn't specified my question right, i just wanted the folder to remain hidden with the "show hidden folders" setting on, but i know that if enought options are enabled/disabled, the file/folder will be visible. And the anwser i was looking for was just what @Steve said

Comment: You can expose an encrypted container as a virtual file system if you want to mimic commercially and freely available secure storage software. If you want that, that question is too broad. If this is for fun, just set those attributes.

Comment: Please do NOT downvote a question just because it's not possible, or because you think the questioner's motivations are 'shady.'  Maybe he's just not familiar enough with how operating systems work.  A better response would be to direct him to encryption, the ProtectedData class, or some other place to hide data users shouldn't be accessing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well now your question is more clear.
You can achieve the same work of your `attrib +h +s folder` command also in C# with

```
File.SetAttributes(@"D:\temp", FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.System);
```

You can set the attributes to your directory to be System and Hidden. But, as you already know, the user can see it if he unchecks the appropriate flags.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the confusion i caused! :D

Comment: Is the answer wrong?

Comment: Nope, its completely right, exactly what I've wanted!

Comment: @GGG I was commenting the downvote. Give a downvote is a right, explain why is a courtesy.

Comment: Note that the user can also see system files if they click that option in Folder Options, as well.  There's no way to fully hide files.  However, you could encrypt them, or prevent their being read by using the ProtectedData class.